# How to increase the query performance on my fts query?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance, postgresql-performance, full-text-search

I'm pretty new to database world and I have the following table:

```
                        Table "public.so_rum"
  Column   |          Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id        | integer                 |           |          | 
 title     | character varying(1000) |           |          | 
 posts     | text                    |           |          | 
 body      | tsvector                |           |          | 
 parent_id | integer                 |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "so_rum_body_idx" rum (body)
```

I have dumped around `27M` record. And I wanted to perform a full text search on my `posts`. `body` is a tsvector for `posts` and it is `rum` indexed.

However, when I run FTS, it is taking a long time. For example:

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYZE select count(*) from so_rum
    where body @@ plainto_tsquery('english','not fast enough data is slow much')
```

give back:

```
                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=188.01..188.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=42207.386..42207.387 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using so_rum_body_idx on so_rum  (cost=180.00..188.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=34716.047..42206.555 rows=497 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (body @@ '''fast'' & ''enough'' & ''data'' & ''slow'' & ''much'''::tsquery)
 Planning Time: 0.247 ms
 Execution Time: 42208.211 ms
(5 rows)
```

Another similar query, but fetching `post` this time:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select posts from so_rum
    where body @@ plainto_tsquery('english',' why java type casting is throwing the exception? How to solve it')
;
                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using so_rum_body_idx on so_rum  (cost=216.00..224.01 rows=1 width=614) (actual time=45155.186..45516.358 rows=31 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (body @@ '''java'' & ''type'' & ''cast'' & ''throw'' & ''except'' & ''solv'''::tsquery)
 Planning Time: 19.540 ms
 Execution Time: 45517.985 ms
(4 rows)
```

How to reduce the query time here? What mistake I'm doing here?

Edit:

SQL query with analyze buffers (this is after `vacuum full analyze`):

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select id from so_rum
    where body @@ plainto_tsquery('english',' what is run time time exception in java')
;
                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using so_rum_body_idx on so_rum  (cost=144.00..300.67 rows=38 width=4) (actual time=462.304..103072.850 rows=9841 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (body @@ '''run'' & ''time'' & ''time'' & ''except'' & ''java'''::tsquery)
   Buffers: shared hit=14898 read=8345
 Planning Time: 0.204 ms
 Execution Time: 103084.358 ms
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Does `VACUUM so_rum;` make a difference?

Comment: Sorry a noob here, what does `VACCUM` does? And how it affects my indexing?

Comment: `VACUUM` does a lot of maintenance jobs on a table (and its indexes), for example removing old and unused data. I don't know if that is a solution, I'm just trying to investigate the problem. What would also be helpful is to see the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks, I tried with `vacuum` but no luck. I had captured with buffers in the question, can you suggest why / where the issue is.

Comment: I have no explanation yet. How big are the table and the index? Is it as slow with a GIN index? If you build a new GIN index on the column, is that smaller than the RUM index?

Comment: The tables are quite big. Yes, the query was slow with GIN and hence I went ahead with RUM index.

Comment: You can use `\di+` to see the index size.

Comment: Repeating the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` with track_io_timing=on would give additional useful information.  Can you show us the plan with the GIN rather than RUM index?